# Shift focus of buttons with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Navigate through the button group with up and down arrow key with angularJS? No Jquery Please.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <div class="btn btn-primary">one</div>
  <div class="btn btn-primary" >Two</div>
  <div class="btn btn-primary">Three</div>
</div>
```